# Power BI unable to connect to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

It was working at first but then I had this error when trying to connect to an SQL server via DirectQuery.

[image]

---

Edit:

According to [this link](https://natechamberlain.com/2019/01/16/unable-to-connect-error-when-accessing-sql-database-in-power-bi-desktop/), I should "run as administrator". Tried that and encountered this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, make sure information in `Default or Custom`, `Windows` and `Database` sections are correct and run as administrator. This worked for me

[image]